# tryton-sao web client doesn't start

Tags: python, tryton

I have a problem, i get a no page found when i run localhost:8000/index.html in the browser after starting the trytond server.I have installed trytond server successfully.I have also installed  tryton-sao web client.(running npm install and grunt).What could i be doing wrong ?

Trytond.conf

```
# /etc/tryton/trytond.conf - Configuration file for Tryton Server    (trytond)

# This file contains the most common settings for trytond (Defaults
# are commented).
# For more information read 
# /usr/share/doc/packages/trytond

[database]
# Database related settings

# The URI to connect to the SQL database (following RFC-3986)
uri =  sqlite://
# (Internal default: sqlite:// (i.e. a local SQLite database))


# The path to the directory where the Tryton Server stores files.
# The server must have write permissions to this directory.
# (Internal default: /var/lib/trytond)


path = /var/lib/trytond

[jsonrpc]
# Settings for the JSON-RPC network interface

# The IP/host and port number of the interface
# (Internal default: localhost:8000)

# Listen on all interfaces (IPv4)


jsonpath_data = /var/tryton-sao-5b6089a3ffa3

listen = localhost:8000


# Listen on all interfaces (IPv4 and IPv6)
listen = localhost:8000

# The hostname for this interface
hostname = localhost

# The root path to retrieve data for GET requests
data = jsondata

timeout = 7000
```

Comment: Which trytond version and sao version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your configuration, you must run tryton 3.8 series.
Your data configuration under jsonrpc seems to be wrong. It should be something like:

```
[jsonrpc]
listen = localhost:8000
data = /var/tryton-sao-5b6089a3ffa3
```